# Настройка Compose в X11

Tags: unix, x11, xcompose

Как я понимаю, все раскладки заимствуют расширенные сочетания клавиш из английской раскладки.

Но почему-то после удаления всех строк из файла `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` и перезагрузки иксов, я всё равно могу напечатать «☹» в три нажатия.

---

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf:
…    Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
    Option "XKbOptions" "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps,compose:ralt"
EndSection
…
```

---

```
/usr/share/X11/locale/ru_RU.UTF-8/Compose:
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"
```

Comment: Простите,в чем заключается суть вопроса?

Comment: В противоречии. Если расширенные сочетания клавиш таки устанавливаются в /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose, то про его очистке они, само собой, работать перестанут. Но таки нет…

Answer (score 2):

т.к. чудес не бывает, стоит обратиться к [документации](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man5/Compose.5.html).

согласно ей, в поисках файла с определениями для *xcompose* просматриваются:

- переменная окружения $XCOMPOSEFILE
- ~/.XCompose
- таблица сопоставления локали и файла `/usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir`

---

вероятнее всего, у вас в домашнем каталоге присутствует файл `.XCompose`, в котором и записано *то самое* правило набора.